# Problemas com NullPointerException em uma classe

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Tenho esse código abaixo que me lança a exceção de `NullPointerException`. Alem disso,estranhamente ele não está "printando" nada,alguém sabe como eu posso resolver?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;



public class SMAReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        URL oracle = new URL("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SMA&symbol=MSFT&interval=30min&time_period=10&series_type=open&apikey=1DZO65QEO50KA0XG");
        URL close = new URL("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SMA&symbol=MSFT&interval=30min&time_period=10&series_type=close&apikey=1DZO65QEO50KA0XG");
        int i;
        Double[] mediaDouble = new Double[10000];//cria o array que vai armazenar as medias em double
        Double[] mediaDoubleClose = new Double[10000];


        try (
            /*BufferedReader, lÃƒÂª o arquivo com mais eficiÃƒÂªncia 
            InputStreamReader, ele converte bytes p caracteres q seria o fluxo"Stream" q entra
            openStream(), abre o acesso do fluxo pela url, ou seja, ele conecta e recupera a informaÃƒÂ§ÃƒÂ£o da pÃƒÂ¡gina   
            */
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()))) {
            String inputLine;//do buffered
            String[] media = new String[10000]; //cria o array que vai armazenar as medias
            String[] mediaClose = new String[10000];//cria o array que vai armazenar as medias do close
            int indiceMedia = 0;//indice do media
            int indiceClose = 0; //indice do close


            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {//enquanto a linha nao estiver vazia
                if (inputLine.contains("SMA")) {//se a linha contiver sma

                    for (i = 0; i < inputLine.length(); i++ ) {//percorre ela
                        if (inputLine.charAt(i) == ':') { //se na linha tbm houver :
                            for (int j = i; j < inputLine.length()-1; j++) { //para j comecando no valor de i,j menor doq inputline-1
                                if (inputLine.substring(13, 16).equals("SMA")) { //se oq estiver nas posicoes de 13 a 16 corresponder a sema
                                    media[indiceMedia++] = inputLine.substring(20, inputLine.length()-1);//vai armazenar esse valor pro array
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }//fim if 2
                    }//fim for
                }//fim if1
            }//fim while


             while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {//enquanto houver linhas
                if (inputLine.contains("close")) {//se a linha contiver close
                    for (i = 0; i < inputLine.length(); i++ ) { //percorre o inputline ate -1 do tamanho dele
                        if (inputLine.charAt(i) == ':') { //se na linha houver :
                            for (int j = i; j < inputLine.length()-1; j++) {//para j = i,j menor doq o tamanho -1 do inputLine
                                if (inputLine.substring(13, 17).equals("close")) {//se oq estiver nas linhas 13 a 17 for igual a close
                                    mediaClose[indiceMedia++] = inputLine.substring(20, inputLine.length()-1);//cria um array que recebe esses valores
                                }//fim if
                            }//fim for
                            break;
                        }//fim if
                    }//fim for
                }//fim if
            }//fim while



            //cria o array que vai armazenar as medias do close em double tambem 
            for (i = 0; i < indiceMedia-1; i++) { //percorre o array
                for(int j = 0;j < indiceClose;j++) //percorre o array
                mediaDouble[i] = Double.parseDouble(media[i]); //e transforma em double
                mediaDoubleClose[i] = Double.parseDouble(mediaClose[i]);
            }//fim do for

            System.out.println("teste");
        } 
        System.out.println("teste"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual a linha do erro? Poste o stacktrace para facilitar...

Comment: Não sei pq tanto downvote. As vezes quando estamos no início, aprendendo, é difícil de explicar qual o problema. Concordo que a pergunta poderia - e deveria - ser melhor formulada, mas acho que o intuito aqui é ajudar/ensinar.

Answer (score 1):

Você está recebendo um `NullPointerException` nessa linha: `mediaDoubleClose[i] = Double.parseDouble(mediaClose[i]);`. Não está "printando" nada, porque antes de chegar na chamada de print, está ocorrendo o erro.

NullPointerException acontece quando você tenta acessar um objeto e esse objeto está nulo. Nesse caso, `mediaClose[i]` é nulo.

Existem algumas formas de resolver, mas o jeito talvez mais simples para te destravar desse problema, seja colocar um null check:

```
  if (mediaClose[i] != null) {
    mediaDoubleClose[i] = Double.parseDouble(mediaClose[i]);
  }
```

Dessa forma, seu programa vai executar e você vai ver a saída no console.

Mais informações (em inglês): https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Preventing_NullPointerException